# How to add Product ID automatically in list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am making a website to display list of products. First three products are hard coded, now i want to add a new Product in the list. After adding product it's ID should be 4 in the list but instead it is showing 0 to me in the list after adding and saving a new product.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As shown in pictures, you can see that the product ID is 0 after adding a new product. Please provide me a solution how can i avoid that 0 and the list should be numbered accordingly.

Code for Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVC5ModelDemo.Models
{
    //model class
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Code for Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVC5ModelDemo.Models;

namespace MVC5ModelDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static List<Product> productList = new List<Product>
        {

            new Product() { ProductId = 01, ProductName = "C# Book", OrderId = 02, Quantity = 2 },
            new Product() { ProductId = 02, ProductName = "ASP.NET Book", OrderId = 02, Quantity = 2 },
            new Product() { ProductId = 03, ProductName = "ASP.NET CORE Book", OrderId = 02, Quantity = 2 }

        };

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(productList.OrderBy(s => s.ProductId).ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult AddProduct()
        {
            //get the product from list
            return View("Add");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddProduct(Product p)
        {
            productList.Add(p);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }


}
```

Code for Add.cshtml:

```
@model MVC5ModelDemo.Models.Product

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

<h2>Add</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Product" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Code for Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC5ModelDemo.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h3>All Product List</h3>
<p align="right">
    <button type="button"
            id="AddButton"
            class="btn btn-primary"
           onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddProduct", "Home")'">
        Add Product

    </button>
</p>
<table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr class="btn-primary">
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ProductId</td>
                <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                <td>@item.OrderId</td>
                <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit","Home", new { i = item.ProductId },null)
                or 
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { i = item.ProductId },null)</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S: I am new to asp.net C#, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Add` method you get a `Product` `p` with `ProductId` set to 0. You then add this new product to the collection and your `Index` method returns your collection sorted by `ProductId`. This way, new items will always have a `ProductId` of `0` and will always show up first.

What you could to is check how many items there are and always take the next available `ProductId` and change your `Add` method to this:

```
int nextProductId = productList.OrderBy(p => p.ProductId).Last().ProductId;
p.ProductId = nextProductId + 1;
productList.Add(p);
```

You do need to be aware that although this will work, it won't be safe to be used by multiple people in parallel. You could end up with duplicate ProductIds.
That's why normally the database comes up with the unique ids and keeps track of them. But for this simple scenario this should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped. This application is just for learning purpose. So that's why i am not using DB in the start.
Just a quick edit: p.ProductId = nextProductId+1;